# Resultados por id do usuário logado

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

tenho uma tabela users com primary_key id
e tenho uma tabela pessoas com um campo user

quero entender como utilizar o relacionamento do laravel para essas tabelas

e quero buscar a pessoa com o id usuario no campo user

Como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como descrito no manual https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships, nas relações One to One você deve criar uma função que retorne um objeto do namespace `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\`, este namespace possui vários tipos de relacionamentos.

Montando as funções onde a pessoa pertence a um usuário, portanto no model **Pessoa**:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}
```

E um usuário tem uma pessoa, desta forma no model **User**:

```
public function pessoa() {
     return $this->hasOne(App\Pessoa::class);
}
```

A relação do tipo `belongsTo` implica em a chave estrangeira existir nesta tabela, por isso, de acordo com sua descrição, neste caso lemos que Pessoa pertence a um Usuário.

E pelo fato do Eloquent tentar resolver o nome das chaves estrangeiras de acordo com o nome das classes relacionadas, seria interessante usar o nome `user_id` para o campo na tabela pessoa. Se pretende utilizar `user` mesmo, é necessário passar às funções o nome personalizado da chave:

Model **Pessoa**:

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class, 'user');
}
```

Model **User**:

```
public function pessoa() {
     return $this->hasOne(App\Pessoa::class, 'user');
}
```

Agora para recuperar a pessoa ou usuário relacionado a um registro, basta chamar o nome da função. Por exemplo:

```
$p = Pessoa::find(xx);
return $p->user->email;

$u = User::find(yy);
return $u->pessoa->sobrenome;
```

Answer (score 1):

Se cada pessoa corresponder a um user então o relacionamento do laravel fica:

No model Pessoa:

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
```

No model User:

```
 public function pessoa() {
            return $this->belongsTo('App\Pessoa');
        }
```